# Format Painter Not Working - Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to copy conditional formatting of cell C1 & C2 (please see the image below) onto the rest of the C cells, but the Format Painter appears to be not doing the job.

As you can see, I am trying to compare column A and C with each other. If the two cells match, I'd like the cell in column C to turn green.

[image]

I have used conditional formatting for the first two cells and want to extend it to the rest of that column.

Here's the file if you'd like to see it:
http://www.mediafire.com/?vv707p3do93rur8

Comment: Although I suspect David is right, you should include the formula for the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @David surmised, an inspection of your worksheet shows that absolute references in the conditional formats you applied to cells C2 and C3 are the problem. To bring up the dialog box shown below, choose the `Conditional Formatting` button on the `Home` tab of the ribbon, and then select `Manage Rules` from the menu that drops down.

[image: conditional formatting setting on sample worksheet]

Easiest fix:

Still in the Rules Manager dialog box:

- Select the second rule - with the reference to $A$3 - and delete it by clicking the `Delete Rule` button.
- Select the first rule - with the reference to $A$2 - and then click the `Edit Rule` button.
- Change the "$A$2" to "A2" and click OK, and OK again.

[image: Edited formatting rule]

And that does it. (As an aside, I didn't expect the `TRUE` value in cell D9 of the example rows I show below. What's happening is that the formula in D9 - `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A9,C:C,0))` -  is getting a match on the value 8 in cell C6. This configuration of values, which I chose at random, may well be impossible to realize in your data.)

[image: View of final formatting with edited conditional format rule]

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you very much for your thorough guide. I was able to fix it following your notes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect format painter itself is working, but your conditional formatting is using absolute references rather than relative. You need to select your first cell (C2) then enter the Conditional Formatting dialog and look at the rule. If the cell reference in the rule has $ dollar signs then that means it's absolute. Just get rid of the dollar signs. Confirm it.

That should sort you out. If you have any issues with lingering rules, you may want to clear your rules and start from scratch (to clear just select your entire column C, then click on Conditional Formatting and 'Clear rules from selected cells').